# Сложности с обособлением запятыми

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужно ли обособлять запятыми "весной" в данном предложении?

> В мае месяце весной почерневшая старая мельница казалась убогой.

Comment: Если из контекста понятно, что мельница находится в северном полушарии, тогда можно написать проще: "в мае почерневшая мельница казалась убогой".

Comment: А число в вопросе что обозначает? Наверное, это номера запятых. Весной, в мае месяце, старая почерневшая мельница казалась убогой ..https://reshak.ru/otvet/otvet16.php?otvet1=402

Comment: Меня интересует постановка запятых , править текст возможности нет, нужно работать с исходником, даже если он не особенно логичный )

Comment: Нельзя менять слова местами, должно быть "в мае месяце весной", а не наоборот!

Comment: Оригинал текста Грина я видела , в экзамене были переставлены слова

Comment: Слова  в экзаменационном тексте лучше переставить обратно. Здесь нет выбора: только одна форма: весной, а именно  в мае.  "Май может только сужать значение "весны", а это уточнение. Другие отношения невозможны, так что ошибка в вашем тексте.